# Ubuntu 15.04 Dota 2 Reborn Beta Not Working

Tags: 15.04, steam, opengl

I use Version 15.04 Ubuntu. I have no problems wıth usage of Dota 2 but Dota 2 Reborn.

It crashes after I see its logo on screen.
The game's logs are in the below

```
Game update: AppID 570 "Dota 2", ProcID 5818, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/realbyx/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/realbyx/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/realbyx/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
pid 5834 != 5833, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/realbyx/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/realbyx/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
Using breakpad crash handler
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 570
Forcing breakpad minidump interfaces to load
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198075820721 [API loaded yes]
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Setting Steam ID:  76561198075820721
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 373300
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(20150604103636)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Fontconfig warning: "/home/realbyx/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/dota 2 beta/game/core/panorama/fonts/conf.d/41-repl-os-win.conf", line 148: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/home/realbyx/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/dota 2 beta/game/core/panorama/fonts/conf.d/41-repl-os-win.conf", line 160: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Hero npc_dota_hero_antimage has no HeroID defined.  This will break stats tracking!Error: VerifyHeroIDs():
Hero npc_dota_hero_antimage has no HeroID defined.  This will break stats tracking!
Attempting to create OpenGL context: v3.3 (Core profile)...success.
Attempting to create OpenGL context: v3.3 (Core profile)...success.
DumpContextInfo: OpenGL vendor NVIDIA Corporation
DumpContextInfo: OpenGL renderer GeForce GTX 670MX/PCIe/SSE2
DumpContextInfo: Using OpenGL context version 3.3
DumpContextInfo: Context supports GLSL version 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
Game removed: AppID 570 "Dota 2", ProcID 5836
```

Answer (score 0):

The dota 2 Reborn, is not yet officially released for all platforms. It is mentioned in their [release page](http://www.dota2.com/reborn/part3/) in multi platform section. The source 2 engine that is used for the game is not yet compatible with the linux and mac versions. Since you are using 15.04 beta, there are more likely chances of getting these errors.

"We're still putting the finishing touches on the Mac and Linux clients and we hope to have them available in the coming weeks." -Dota2 Official website

Most beta versions of games or software are not multi-platform compatible. It leaves us with no choice to wait until they release a stable version in couple of weeks.

Comment: My friend play ubuntu 14.04 no problem.

Comment: The question is about 15.04, which is a beta version of ubuntu. and the Dota 2 reborn, which is also a latest beta version. There are pretty high chances of getting compatibility errors. Even i play dota2 in ubuntu 14.04 with no errors because 14.04 is a stable OS and dota 2 as well. But it is not the same case with 15.04 and reborn beta

Comment: Hi you play reborn beta ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: My friend say me, ubuntu 14.04 reborn beta working

Comment: I play reborn on another windows pc. Because i have ubuntu15.04. Im waiting for the stable release of reborn. You might have to post this in http://www.playdota.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1458839  to get more details